# WAF Protection for api gateway using websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, web-application-firewall

I have a use case where i am supposed to connect my client to apigateway using websockets. I have seen the API gateway can be configured with WAF rules in case of a REST api but i am not able to see the websockets API gateway under the list of resources that can be added to WAF protected resource in AWS console. Does it mean that websocket connections to API gateway cannot be protected using WAF ?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, WAF cannot be used with a WebSocket API in Amazon API Gateway. However, by configuring authorizer and throttling, you can protect your API.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-protect.html